# Sandbox seems to be enabled on my App, but the App Store disagrees

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

When attempting to upload my App to the App Store I'm getting the following error message:

ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list:" - (path_to_my_app)"

However, I've already enabled the sandbox in the capabilities folder of my App, and in the Entitlements plist. Any idea as to why this could be happening?

Comment: I was facing the same issue, turns out I did not sign the app thus the entitlements were not being applied.

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be the issue for me as well.